# Regex to only let two words: either male or female

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I need to let through into SQL query only two words: either *male* or *female*

I use PHP function that returns:

```
return preg_replace( "/([male|female])/i", '', $data );
```

At the moment it removes these words but how do I delete absolutely everything and let only

 either *male* or *female*?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original pattern would match any `m`, `a`, `l`, `e`, `|`, or `f` character.

You probably want something like this:

```
if (preg_match('/(fe)?male/i', $data, $match))
    return $match[0];
else
    return "";
```

Or in a one-liner:

```
return preg_match('/(fe)?male/i', $data, $match) ? $match[0] : "";
```

This will match the literal string `male` (preceded by the optional literal string `fe`) and return the first matched result. If no such match is found, it will return an empty string.

Comment: I was misusing `preg_match`. Thank you very much for detailed example and explanation!

Comment: This will trigger a notice if neither of this words exists in the string.

Comment: @Glavić I had tested it and didn't get any notice, but since I was just echoing the results, it looked to me like an empty string. You are right, in that case `$match[0]` would be `NULL`. I've updated it to be a bit safer.

Answer (score 3):

To do what you're describing, you can perhaps use this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/.*?((?:fe)?male).*/i', '$1', $str);
```

This will remove everything and place back `female` or `male` in the string.

[codepad demo](http://codepad.org/kzAgIYzv).

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Yes sorry, I noticed the other answers only after hitting submit ^^;

Comment: +1 but there seems to be something wrong with this solution. `preg_replace('/.*((?:fe)?male).*/i', '$1', 'female');` returns `male`. I think you need a `?` after the first `.*`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Hmm, you're right. The `.` consumes the fe from the female o_o

Comment: Also there's a slight difference between this solution and mine. If the input is `"spoo"` (doesn't contain either `male` or `female`) this will return `"spoo"` (unmodified input string), but mine will return `""` (no match). Both are fine, depending on what exactly you need.